# How do I write a generic groupByKey for a Traversable[(K, V)] in scala <= 2.12

Tags: scala, generics, scala-collections

It's pretty easy to write a function from `List[(K, V)]` to `Map[K, List[V]]`:

```scala
def groupByKey[K, V](
  pairs: List[(K, V)]
): Map[K, List[V]] =
  pairs
    .groupBy(_._1)
    .mapValues(_.map(_._2))
```

but it seems a shame it's collection type specific.

I can generalise it of course to

```scala
def groupByKey[K, V](
  pairs: Traversable[(K, V)]
): Map[K, Traversable[V]] =
  pairs
    .groupBy(_._1)
    .mapValues(_.map(_._2))
```

but now I've got a `Traversable` back and I'd quite like the same type I put in, since `groupBy` does that for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Worked it out.

As a method:

```scala
def groupByKey[K, V, Repr <: TraversableLike[(K, V), Repr], That <: TraversableLike[V, That]](
  pairs: TraversableLike[(K, V), Repr]
)(implicit
  bf: CanBuildFrom[Repr, V, That]
): Map[K, That] = pairs
  .groupBy(_._1)
  .mapValues(_.map(_._2))
```

As an implicit class:

```scala
implicit class GroupByKey[K, +V, +Repr <: TraversableLike[(K, V), Repr], +That <: TraversableLike[V, That]](
  decorated: TraversableLike[(K, V), Repr]
)(implicit
  bf: CanBuildFrom[Repr, V, That]
) {
  def groupByKey: Map[K, That] = decorated
    .groupBy(_._1)
    .mapValues(_.map(_._2))
}
```