# How do I write a generic groupByKey for a collection of (K, V) in scala >= 2.13

Tags: scala

I am upgrading code from Scala 2.12 to Scala 2.13

I have code grouping `Traversable[(K, V)]` by key, as an implicit class:

```scala
implicit class TraversableLikeGroupingOps[K, V, R[A] <: TraversableLike[A, R[A]]](val tuples: R[(K, V)]) extends AnyVal {
  def groupPairsByFirstElement(implicit ev: CanBuildFrom[R[(K, V)], V, R[V]]): Map[K, R[V]] = {
    tuples.groupBy(_._1).mapValuesStrict(_.map(_._2))
  }
}
```

See: [How do I write a generic groupByKey for a Traversable[(K, V)] in scala <= 2.12](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59987545/how-do-i-write-a-generic-groupbykey-for-a-traversablek-v-in-scala-2-12)

Unfortunately, `TraversableLike` is missing in Scala 2.13

How do I port this code to Scala 2.13?

Minimal expectations:

```
Set[(K, V)]  -> Map[K, Set[V]]
List[(K, V)] -> Map[K, List[V]]
```

Comment: Why not just `groupMap(_._1)(_._2)`?

Comment: @LuisMiguelMejíaSuárez This is great - if you write an answer, I'm going to accept it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As @[LuisMiguelMejíaSuárez](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4111404/luis-miguel-mej%c3%ada-su%c3%a1rez) mentioned, you can use `groupMap`. Here you have two articles that shows what changes were introduced in collections for `scala 2.13`

- [MIGRATING A PROJECT TO SCALA 2.13'S COLLECTIONS](https://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/core/collections-migration-213.html)

> ##### Are there new operations on collections?
>
> The following new partitioning operations are available:
>
> ```scala
> def groupMap[K, B](key: A => K)(f: A => B): Map[K, CC[B]] // (Where `CC` can be `List`, for instance)
> def groupMapReduce[K, B](key: A => K)(f: A => B)(g: (B, B) => B): Map[K, B]
> ```
>
> `groupMap` is equivalent to `groupBy(key).mapValues(_.map(f))`.
>
> `groupMapReduce` is equivalent to `groupBy(key).mapValues(_.map(f).reduce(g))`.

- [SCALA 2.13’S COLLECTIONS](https://www.scala-lang.org/blog/2018/06/13/scala-213-collections.html)

> ##### New And Noteworthy
>
> We have introduced a few new operations. The following sections present some of them.
>
> `groupMap`
>
> A common pattern with the old 2.12 collections is to use `groupBy` followed by `mapValues` to transform the groups. For instance, this is how we can index the names of a collection of users by their age:
>
> ```scala
> case class User(name: String, age: Int)
>
> def namesByAge(users: Seq[User]): Map[Int, Seq[String]] =
>   users.groupBy(_.age).mapValues(users => users.map(_.name))
> ```